# How can i make the shape background for the rectangle have a sharp cut in the bottom edges?

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<solid android:color="#FDC700" />


<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" />
```

This is the result that i need , the edges be the red one without the yellow part

[image: this is the result that i need , the edges be the red one without the yellow part].

Comment: In which view do you want to apply this shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using vector drawables:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="20"
    android:viewportHeight="40">

  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0 L 0,35 L 5,40 L15,40 L20,35 L20,0 Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</vector>
```

Final result looks like this:

[image: generated drawable]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` if you need a view to serve as a container. [Read here about shapes](https://material.io/design/shape/about-shape.html#shaping-material) in Material UI.

*Note: any Material surface supports such behaviour.*

You can [read here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape) more about how to apply shapes in your application.

#### Example

*You way notice shadow artefacts on the screenshots below. Do not worry, they are visible only in the Design tab of layout editor.*

Lets consider the next layout and style:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/BottomCutCornersShape" />
```

Style (stored in styles.xml):

```
<style name="BottomCutCornersShape" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50dp</item>
</style>
```

The result you will achieve is next:

[image: Result material card view with bottom corners cut]

`MaterialCardView` will make sure any content inside of it is not cut:

[image: Example with content]

#### Every material view can apply shape

We can apply the same style to the image view from the aforementioned example. The result will look like this:

[image: Example with the shape style applied to the image]

You can basically do anything you want regarding shapes.

[image: Rounded image and random corners on the material card view]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) provided by the Material Components Library:

In your layout just use something like:

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:backgroundTint="@color/...."
      android:id="@+id/shape_layout"/>
```

Then in your code:

```
   float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius64); //64dp for example

    LinearLayout shapeLayout = findViewById(R.id.shape_layout);
    ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel.builder()
            .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 0f)
            .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, radius)
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, radius)
            .build();

    MaterialShapeDrawable materialShapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
    ViewCompat.setBackground(shapeLayout,materialShapeDrawable);
```

[image]